# Spring Security (5.7.3): this.authenticationManager is null

Tags: spring-security, jwt

I'm trying POST requests to login to the page with JWT Authentication.
I had initially tried to do JWT Authentication using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter. But WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter is deprecated. I then tried to integrate it according to the new usage.But When I send POST request in Postman, I m getting this error.

```
"org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager.authenticate(org.springframework.security.core.Authentication)" because "this.authenticationManager" is null
```

My Dependencies are:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.project</groupId>
<artifactId>questapp</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>questapp</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>17</java.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My Controller Class is:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/auth")
public class AuthenticationController {


private  AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
private JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider;

@PostMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestBody UserRequest userLoginRequest) {
    
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userLoginRequest.getUserName(), userLoginRequest.getPassword());
    
    Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authenticationToken);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
    
    String jwtToken = jwtTokenProvider.generateJwtToken(auth);
    return "Bearer "+jwtToken;
}
```

}

My SecurityConfig Class is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

private final UserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
private final JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint handler;

@Bean
public JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter() {
    return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
}

 @Bean
 public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(jwtUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
        return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
 }   
@Bean
public CorsFilter corsFilter() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    config.addAllowedHeader("*");
    config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
    config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
    config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
    config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
    config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
    config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    
   return new CorsFilter(source);
}
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception{
    httpSecurity
        .cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(handler).and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/auth/**")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();
    
    return httpSecurity.build();
        
}

}
```

Can anyone tell me where I made a mistake?

Comment: what is the reason for you to write a custom JWTFilter and not using the built in functionality of spring security https://thomasandolf.medium.com/spring-security-jwts-getting-started-ebdb4e4f1dd1

Comment: I'm only at the beginning of the road in programming. I just used it to both learn and understand how it works. I actually did this without knowing that WebSecurityAdapter was deprecated. I then tried to integrate this and blew it.

Comment: If you want to learn, you should always start with the official documentation

Comment: how did you inject your `AuthenticationManager` bean to a controller? I don't see constructor injection nor field injection through `@Autowired`

Comment: Than you Andrew. I think I had a major oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Set the AuthenticationManager with HttpSecurity

```
@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity, 
AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) throws Exception{
    httpSecurity
        .cors()
        .and()
        .csrf().disable()
        .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), 
     UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
    .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
    .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(handler).and()
    .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,"/auth/**")
        .permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/auth/**")
        .permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

    return httpSecurity.build();
    
}
```